# Website redirections not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I have a website https://recruitcrm.io

The problem with my website is when I enter any links among those shown below, it goes to the homepage. But I want to redirect my links according to the arrows. What should I do in order to fix this and make it work the way I want?

1. https://www.recruitcrm.io → https://recruitcrm.io (www should be truncated)
2. https://www.recruitcrm.io/pricing → https://recruitcrm.io/pricing
3. https://recruitcrm.io/pricing → https://recruitcrm.io/pricing

Any help would be appreciated greatly. I have tried many combinations in my htaccess file but I got no luck, only frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://recruitcrm.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Note that Apache’s mod_rewrite module needs to be enabled. Otherwise, the above snippet won’t work.**

---

**Now, in Nginx this snippet is a bit different, but yields the exact same result when placed in the proper configuration file (which depends on your setup):**

```
server {

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;

}
```